# Responsive centering with fixed position

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to center the navigation, but I haven't succeeded yet. The idea is that the navigation moves along as the user scrolls the page. It has to be responsive as well, because navigation should always be displayed. So I've come up with this:

```
<nav id="nav" class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#avaleht" class="avaleht" title="Avaleht" >avaleht</a></li>
        <li><a href="#massaazh" class="massaazh" title="Massaaž" >massaaž</a></li>
        <li><a href="#kontakt" class="kontakt" title="Kontakt" >kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
#nav
{
    position: fixed;
}

#nav ul
{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav a
{
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 100px;
}

#nav a.avaleht
{
    background: rgb(168,191,18);
}

#nav a.massaazh
{
    background: rgb(255,159,0);
}

#nav a.kontakt
{
    background: rgb(0,170,181);
}

#nav a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgb(66,64,62);
}
```

And this is how I'd like it to work:

[image: Prototype]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `left:0; right:0;` to the fixed `#nav` element:

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    left:0; right:0;
}
```

Then remove the `margin-right` for the last `li` element's child anchor element:

```
#nav li:last-child a {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VrC4E/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    left:0; 
    right:0;
}
```

and replace margin-right:80 with margin:5px 40px

```
#nav a{
     margin: 5px 40px;
}
```